# Which policy do I use for redirect RaiseFault or AssignMessage?

Tags: apigee

I want to do a redirect during API processing..basically redirect to my login page and require the user to authenticate.  Should I use AssignMessage or RaiseFault Apigee Policy?  And, what's the difference?

Answer (score 0):

A Raise Fault Policy will stop all processing and return the payload to your client. AssignMessage will keep on going to the backend target and running policies only with the new Payload that you define.

So... RaiseFault.

And, as in the comments, the RaiseFault policy will only be recorded in Analytics as an error if you return a non-success code (2xx and 3xx are not considered errors so if you do a 302 redirect, it won't be tracked as an error).

Comment: Would RaiseFault not show error count in analytics? On the other hand you can use a routing rule to avoid sending some requests to backend conditionally and use a null target + assign message to send redirect responses.

Comment: Santanu, can you explain in an answer of its own so that we can vote?

Comment: Took a minute and tested this today -- if you return an an http code in the 2XX or 3XX range it will not be logged as an error even if you use the RaiseFault policy.